# State Functions and Change in state functions

Tags: thermodynamics

So, I have been studying thermodynamics, in it I read that state functions are those functions which depend only on one state of the system and are independent of the path taken, which is pretty easy to understand. And this clears why properties like enthalpy, pressure, volume etc are state functions.
Then there was the statement,

> Change in a state function is not a state function.

which took me some time to understand, but I got it once I referred to the original definition of a state function. But now when I read about Hess law, which basically states that change in a state function is independent of the path taken, I'm confused as doesn't this imply that change in state function is infact a state function. Can someone please clarify this.

Comment: It might help for you to give a more precise definition of a “state function” (e.g. quoted from one of the books you read).

Comment: @robphy I have read this definition or definitions very similar to this, " A state function are the properties of a system which depend only on the state of the system and not on how this state is achieved."

Answer (score 0):

Thermodynamics has states (equilibrium states) and processes driving a thermodynamic system from one state to another.

Some quantities may depend only on the state, while others may rely on the state *and* the process ending in that state. An example of the former kind of quantity is the temperature of a thermodynamic system. Non-adiabatic work is an example of the latter.

With the previous definition, a change in a state function, depending on the initial state, in addition to the final state, but not on the process, would not be, strictly speaking, a state function, even if it is not process-dependent. However, this definition problem can be overcome by choosing one common reference state, thus defining the zero level for changes. At this point, even a change of a state function behaves as a state function.

An example is the potential energy. The meaningful quantity we can introduce is a difference (change) of potential energy between two points. However, as soon as we decide to have the potential at one fixed point (for example, at infinity) as a reference, we can meaningfully speak about the potential energy as a function of a single point.

Comment: But isn't the inherent definition of a state function is that it depends on one and only one state of the function. Also this doesn't really clarify my doubt regarding hess law.

Comment: @bm27 The real important point is the difference between process-dependent quantities and process-independent. The difference between "absolute quantities" defined for each individual state and the difference between state functions is a minor one. As I tried to explain i is enough to use a standard reference point to transform a difference of state function into a state function.

Comment: ok got this part, but if we apply hess law to a process, it is not necessary that the process's initial point was at infinity, for eg. for a chemical process intial enthalpy in Delta H may have some non zero value.

Comment: @bm27 Yes. It is not necessary that the process's initial point was at infinity. However, we have a state variable once the reference point has been chosen.